# Automapper exception

Tags: c#, automapper

The following mapping code causes automapper to throw an exception when the map is done.

```
mapper.CreateMap<SqlDataReader, CodeModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, 
                 options => options.MapFrom(src => src["code"] != null ? 
                                                   src["code"].ToString() :
                                                   string.Empty));
```

This is really bizarre, `src["code"]` has a value, it is `"E"`, this is even stated in the automapper message.

Does anyone have any insight into what this issue or how to solve this issue?

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +116
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +459
>
> [AutoMapperMappingException:
>
> Mapping types: String -> String System.String -> System.String
>
> Destination path: CodeModel.Code
>
> Source value: E]
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +537
>   AutoMapper.Mappers.DataReaderMapper.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext
>   context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap
>   propertyMap) +305
>   AutoMapper.Mappers.DataReaderMapper.MapPropertyValues(ResolutionContext
>   context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object result) +210
>   AutoMapper.Mappers.DataReaderMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context,
>   IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +639
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +477    AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type
>   sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts) +176
>
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Action`1 opts) +162
>   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source) +143

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ResolveUsing` method, instead of the method `MapFrom`, but in your case both these methods should work as expected. Try to see if any configuration issues are present.

```
  mapper.CreateMap<SqlDataReader, CodeModel>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, 
                     options => options.ResolveUsing(src => src["code"] != null ? 
                                                       src["code"].ToString() :
                                                       string.Empty));
```

I have created a working sample with SqlReaderMock. I assume your context of SqlReader execution is good.

```
//Arrange
var configStore = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
configStore.CreateMap<SqlDataReaderMock, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src["tyto"] != null
                                                                        ? src["tyto"].ToString()
                                                                        : String.Empty));
var _mappingEngine = new MappingEngine(configStore);

//Act
var result = _mappingEngine.Map<Destination>(new SqlDataReaderMock());

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual("otyt", result.Name);


class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


class SqlDataReaderMock
{
    public string this[string value]
    {
        get
        {
            return new string(value
                                    .ToCharArray()
                                    .Reverse()
                                    .ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you then please check the AutoMapper Configuration?

Comment: There basically is no configuration... We've had to work around this issue without using automapper !!